# Does exist any way to convert TIFF image from little-endian byte order to big-endian?

Tags: java, image, tiff, endianness

I have .dll library which use tiff image in big-endian (MM) byte order, but image scanner create image in little-endian (II) byte order.

How to convert tiff from little-endian (II) to big-endian (MM)?

Will be great, watch how it make in java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with **ImageMagick** like this:

```
convert image.tif -define tiff:endian=msb msb.tif
```

Here is the *before* image with Intel byte ordering (`II`):

```
xxd image.tif| more
0000000: 4949 2a00 0800 0600 ffff 0000 0000 ffff  II*.............
```

And here is the *after* image with Motorola ordering (`MM`):

```
xxd msb.tif| more
0000000: 4d4d 002a 0006 0008 ffff 0000 0000 ffff  MM.*............
```

Comment: May be exists any inmemory solutions? I mean solutions used by API.

Answer (score 0):

The ImageMagick package's convert tool seems to be able to do this.
The command line would be something like:

```
convert myllfile.tiff -endian MSB mymmfile.tiff
```